# Is CocoaPods always required to build Cordova ios app?

Tags: ios, cordova, cocoapods

After running:

> cordova requirements

I get the following result:

Requirements check results for ios:
Apple OS X: installed darwin
Xcode: installed 8.2.1
ios-deploy: installed 1.9.1
CocoaPods: not installed 
CocoaPods was not found. Please install version 1.0.1 or greater from https://cocoapods.org/
Error: Some of requirements check failed

But I would like to know if CocoaPods is really required for every Cordova application or only the applications that actually make use of CocoaPods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using cordova for a hybrid project for first time and it compiles without making use of cocoapods. Try with an example:

[Cordova examples](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error by running

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

**Here is the error**

$cordova requirements

Requirements check results for ios:
Apple OS X: installed darwin
Xcode: installed 8.3.2
ios-deploy: installed 1.9.1

*CocoaPods: not installed 
Version should contain only numbers and dots
Error: Some of requirements check failed*